# Designing an index for a postgres query

Tags: database, performance, postgresql, indexing, profiling

We have a query that retrieves some data from a master-detail simple schema. the *WHERE* clause looks like:

```
-- These are just random numbers
Where ticket.type_id in ( 2, 3, 4, 5, 7 ) and
      (
         ticket.color_id is null or
         ticket.color_id in ( 1, 2 , 8 )
      )
```

we already have indexes in the columns: ticket.type_id and ticket.color_id, anyway the QUERY EXPLAIN ANALYZE still show us that Postgresql is making a sequential scan to satisfy the query.

This query is really important and recurrent in the system, so we want to create an index specially for this case.

#### What index could solve this case?

Comment: If you just do `Where ticket.type_id in ( 2, 3, 4, 5, 7 )` will it use the index?

Comment: It probably believes doing a sequential scan of the table is faster than re-scanning the index for each ID in the IN clause.  Unless the table is very large and the specified `type_id`s are a small fraction of the data, it's probably right.

Comment: in this case, is a big table (millions of records), any extra ideas?

Comment: Can you paste in the `EXPLAIN` for `Where ticket.type_id in ( 2, 3, 4, 5, 7 )`?

Comment: Some names change, this is http://pastebin.com/Xq3kjmNg

Comment: 'What index could solve this case?' -- I think you need more optimizer hints, not more indexes. More indexes might in fact hurt the transaction processing (if this isn't a reporting database)

Comment: @Dario - This one's a bit over my head, so I'll let some PG expert chime in.  However, suffice to say that just because you have an index doesn't mean in will get used if PG thinks it will be overall slower.  Make sure your stats are up to date as well.

Comment: @sehe - PG doesn't support optimizer hints.

Comment: @MikeChristensen that's a shame. I can only recommend trying to tweak things using (a) different query structure (`join` instead of `id in (...)`?), different index field type (make it not support bitmap scans...), or possibly readonly views (which would behave as the subquery in a join, but might get indexes in some RDBMS implementations)

Comment: @sehe - Yea, optimizer hints seems to be a bit of a religious war in the Postgres community from what I've heard.  I think the argument is that if you need to use hints, you're probably not writing your query right in the first place.

Comment: Please provide the whole query. Is it only a simple `WHERE`? Does it have `HAVING`? `ORDER BY`? `LIMIT`? How many tables are joined?

Comment: Of course, this is the query: http://pastebin.com/nH9mcr7X (it includes an aggregated function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not real sure - but i think the null is getting yuo..

maybe an oddball looking structure like this

```
Where ticket.type_id in ( 2, 3, 4, 5, 7 ) and
      (
         nvl(ticket.color_id,1) in ( 1, 2 , 8 )
      )
```

Comment: Nvl() is An Oracle function. Use coalesce(), but this can't use an index.

Answer (score 3):

First, check that an index will actually help you.  Turn off sequence scans to force index usage before your query is called:

```
SET ENABLE_SEQSCAN TO OFF;
```

After your query runs:

```
SET ENABLE_SEQSCAN TO ON;
```

to re-enable sequence scans.  If this shows no performance improvement Postgres is already choosing the correct execution plan (sequence scan).  I'd run an `explain analyze <query>` for the entire query with sequence scan both on and off.

Have you run a `vacuum analyze` on the relevant tables?  It's possible the planner doesn't have correct or current statistics for your query.